# log4j logging file exclude logs messages

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, spring-logback

I am building spring boot application version `2.0.2.RELEASE` with BOM `Finchley.RC2` and trying to write logs to file in using `log4j2.xml` . The problem is i want to log only my application messages like:

```
log.error("this is error");
log.info("this is info");
```

but the log file is showing other logs as well like Spring logs etc as below:

```
29-08-2018 18:01:45,023 [INFO ] [] [main] - this is info
29-08-2018 18:01:45,492 [INFO ] [] [main] - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@b4711e2: startup date [Wed Aug 29 18:01:45 PKT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
29-08-2018 18:01:45,659 [INFO ] [] [main] - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
29-08-2018 18:01:45,687 [INFO ] [] [main] - Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$af5d2aa2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

How I can customize my `log4j2.xml` to acheive only my application logging for info/debug/error logs.
Below is my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="mylogFile.log" 
        append="true" filePattern="log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] [%X{X-B3-TraceId}] [%t] - %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] [%X{X-B3-TraceId}] [%t] - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="JSONAppender" fileName="\\tmp\\logFile.json.log" append="true">

    <JSONLayout complete="true" charset="UTF-8" compact="true" eventEol="true"/>

    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml" level="info" >
      <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="guru.springframework.blog.log4j2json" level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="JSONAppender"/>
    </Logger>


    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
      <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="JSONAppender"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>`
```

Any help please what is wrong with my configration?
With Spring `1.5.9 version` it was working fine but as i upgrade to `2.0.2.RELEASE` logging to file not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid `INFO` from external libraries you need to adjust the root log level from `INFO` to `WARN` or `ERROR`.

In addition you have to create an explicit logger for the packages/classes you want to write log messages from.

```
<Logger name="com.my.app" level="info">
  <AppenderRef="STDOUT" />
  ..
</Logger>
```

I would also recommend that you add the logger (`%c`) to the log pattern.